# yii get current page number

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.16 and am trying to get the current page number. I counld just use `$_GET['page']` but was wondering if there is a away to do so in Yii.

I tried this,

```
print_r($pagination = $dataProvider->pagination);
echo $pagination->currentPage.'<br />';
echo $pagination->pageSize.'<br />';
```

but even though i'm on page 10, i get this

```
CPagination Object ( [pageVar] => page [route] => [params] => [validateCurrentPage] => 1 [_pageSize:CPagination:private] => 10 [_itemCount:CPagination:private] => 0 [_currentPage:CPagination:private] => [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => ) 
0
10
```

the page size is correct, but the current page number isn't. 
i would like to have a a custom previous and next button outside my clistview, is that possible?

Comment: Do you use ajax for pagination?

Comment: @styopdev  yes, but on some clistview's i don't

Comment: Try this method $dataProvider->pagination->getCurrentPage()

Comment: @styopdev i get 0 too, and i'm on page 10 now

Comment: Did you call getCurrentPage() after CListView widget call ?

Comment: no before, i want to have a previous and next button outside my clistview, is that possible?

Comment: try Yii::app()->request->getParam('page');

Comment: i`m not sure, but i think you cant do it before widget initialization.

Comment: @styopdev i see, just thought of adding a previous/next button above my clistview

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 :

```
$dataProvider->pagination->page
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view, this works for me:

```
$widget->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage
```

With $widget you get the Clistview widget then you acces the current page.

The widget is initialize with this code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView', array(
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'itemView' => '_view',
     'template' => '{items} {pager}',
));
```